# Read all contacts (including imported from facebook, etc)

Tags: android

According to this sample: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html 
I wrote a simple function for getting all contacts:

```
 Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +
            (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
```

It works well but it dosn't return contacts imported with Facebook application (but they are visible in the Contacts application). Any idea on how to read all the contacts like in the Contacts application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at the `RawContacts` to find out that information.

Here's what the Android [Contacts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) docs say:

> A row in the RawContacts table represents the set of Data and other
>   information describing a person and associated with a single contacts
>   source. For example, a row might define the data associated with a
>   person's Google or Exchange account or Facebook friend. For more
>   information, see ContactsContract.RawContacts.

The [RawContacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) docs say:

> The best way to read a raw contact along with all the data associated
>   with it is by using the ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity directory.
>   If the raw contact has data rows, the Entity cursor will contain a row
>   for each data row. If the raw contact has no data rows, the cursor
>   will still contain one row with the raw contact-level information.

There's also some sample code there:

```
 Uri rawContactUri = 
   ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);

 Uri entityUri = 
   Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

 Cursor c = 
   getContentResolver().query(entityUri,
                              new String[]{RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, 
                                           Entity.DATA_ID, 
                                           Entity.MIMETYPE, 
                                           Entity.DATA1},
                              null, 
                              null, 
                              null);
 try 
 {
     while (c.moveToNext()) 
     {
         String sourceId = c.getString(0);

         if (!c.isNull(1)) 
         {
             String mimeType = c.getString(2);
             String data = c.getString(3);
             ...
         }
     }
 } 
 finally 
 {
     c.close();
 }
```

Comment: what is rawContactId and where to get it

Comment: this isn't helpful at all, given that the issue is getting the contacts from the provider in the first place. this answer takes you nowhere...

Answer (score 1):

It is mention in so many threads FaceBook contact can't be read by third party application only the system application or activity can read.So on any android phone 'DirectDial' and 'DirectMessage' which some one can create by  long press on home screen can read the facebook contact . So I dig into Android Source code to find  what is it there to read the facebook contact.

My findings .

To create shortcut for 'DirectDial' , 'DirectMessage' and ContactShortcut it will launch ContactSelectionActivity which will return the Intent as result having Contact information 'name' 'number' and 'icon' .If somebudy what to dig into that here is the link for the same

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ContactSelectionActivity.java

So how to launch the 'DirectDial' or 'DirectMessage' from within your code 
I look in the AndroidManifest.xml

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

```
      <activity-alias android:name="alias.DialShortcut"
        android:targetActivity=".activities.ContactSelectionActivity"
        android:label="@string/shortcutDialContact"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_shortcut_directdial"
        android:enabled="@*android:bool/config_voice_capable">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_MODE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity-alias>

    <activity-alias android:name="alias.MessageShortcut"
        android:targetActivity=".activities.ContactSelectionActivity"
        android:label="@string/shortcutMessageContact"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_shortcut_directmessage"
        android:enabled="@*android:bool/config_voice_capable">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity-alias>
```

Here they create alias of ContactSelectionActivity to launch 'DirectDial' or 'DirectMessage'

So here is the code to lauch directdial or message

```
  private boolean launchContactSelector() {
    ComponentName distantActivity;
    if (Constants.PHONE_CALL)  //check what you want to call
        distantActivity = new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "alias.DialShortcut");
    else {
        distantActivity = new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "alias.MessageShortcut");
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(distantActivity);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, selector);
    return true;

}
```

Once the contact is selected

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent = ((Intent) data.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT));
    switch (requestCode) {
    case Constants.PHONE_CALL: {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        break;
    }
    case Constants.MESSAGE: {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        break;
    }
    }
    String number = intent.getData().toString(); //It will have the phone number 

    String name = data.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME); //Contact name 
    ImageView image = new ImageView() //Contact image 
    image.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON));

    // Must need to set the Intent.ACTION_SENDTO or Intent.ACTION_CALL  because default          permission sent is CALL_PRIVILEGED which is for system Activty you .    

   startActivity(data);

    }
```

So it  possible to read facebook contact within your app Now store the information some where for future use .

I will post the link of my open source app once it is complete where  I am actually using this .