# How can I read contacts other then from "Google" account?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I have a number of accounts configured on my device (Android 3.2):

- com.android.exchange (Exchange)
- com.facebook.auth.login (Facebook)
- com.twitter.android.auth.login (Twitter)
- com.google (Google)

But when I try to read contacts, all I get is contacts from "Google" account.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
...
```

I saw a comment about [facebook contacts restrictions](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/95110dd7a1e1e0b4), that actually makes no sense for me.

**Question.** So how can I retrieve the same set of contacts that "Contacts" application shows?

**UPDATE:** I was wrong about "Twitter" and "Exchange", they works good. The only problem with "Facebook".

Answer (score 1):

[Post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/95110dd7a1e1e0b4/639dfd583ccc3e8a?lnk=gst&q=read%20facebook%20contacts#639dfd583ccc3e8a):

> **Dmitri Plotnikov**: Access to Facebook friends via the contacts provider is restricted to
>   a handful of system apps by the provider itself. Other applications
>   cannot  read that data.

[Post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bb64ddc1b054a412/624aa3480f9a7db8?lnk=gst&q=read%20facebook%20contacts#624aa3480f9a7db8):

> **piyu**: ... but problem is I am not getting restricted contacts of facebook...
>
> **Dmitri Plotnikov**: Unfortunately the answer is no.  That is a policy established by
>   facebook  and is specific to facebook.  No other sync adapter creates
>   restricted raw  contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Link where I posted how to read all the contact include facebook

[Read all contacts (including imported from facebook, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946766/read-contacts-all-contacts-also-imported-from-facebook-etc/16035138#16035138)